# facebooksdk's FBAndroid-2.0.apk are we supposed to install this along with our app?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

First, let me apologize if this is a repeat question.  I did a search but didn't see a similar one.  My question is this.  Are we supposed to somehow always include FBAndroid-2.0.apk alongside the app that we develop for android that needs to use Facebook?  So let's say I put MyCoolAppWithFacebook.apk on GooglePlay, am I supposed to package it together with FBAndroid-2.0.apk ?  If so how can this be done?  The facebook developer site have you install it using 'adb' too, as in 'adb install'.  If I was to put FBAndroid-2.0.apk inside MyCoolAppWithFacebook/bin folder, it gets deleted every time I do a clean from Eclipse.  Maybe I am missing something.  Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: "The Facebook SDK uses Facebook's native app to provide support for authentication when it's present. On a real device, you can simply install this app for free from Google Play to test this out. However, it's not possible to access Google Play on an emulator, so if you want to test the flow there, we include an copy in the SDK that you can install."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  They have you install it on the simulator for testing purposes.  When a user attempts to use facebook from your app the facebook SDK will either open the native facebook app (if it is installed on the users device) or it will open the browser and handle the authentication through their website.

Comment: So how do we make sure the "native facebook app" get installed on the users device?  Do with include it inside MyCoolAppWithFacebook/bin folder ?

Comment: It shouldn't matter if the native app is installed.  What are you needing the facebook app for?  Is it to allow your user to login with facebook?

Comment: The native facebook app is not required for your users.  They will have a better experience if it is there.  The FBAndroid-2.0.apk is included so you can test your application with and without the facebook app installed, and you can do so programmatically as part of your test pass, and on an emulator that does not have Play Store.